# AWS Role recommendation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

We are a company and we have AWS accounts for users who are organized using IAM Roles. Although accounts are personal, users must use different Roles to perform different tasks.

We have a role called **traine**, used for experiments and certification preparation.

My question: What do you suggest in terms of policy to attach to this role?

Big thanks,

Regards

#### Update

I have attached these policies with account but it seems too large:

```
 AmazonRDSFullAccess
 AmazonEC2FullAccess
 AmazonS3FullAccess
 AmazonRoute53ReadOnlyAccess
 AmazonVPCFullAccess
 AmazonRoute53AutoNamingFullAccess
 IAMReadOnlyAccess
 AmazonElasticFileSystemFullAccess
```

Comment: What a trainee will be able to do? Create instances, launch EKS clusters, create new users, run codebuild jobs? Policies depend on what the trainees will be able to do.

Comment: This my question, "what should i  give to the trainee"

Comment: Only you can possibly know what your role needs to be able to do. Once you know that, you can determine what rights are required to perform those actions.